# Emu8086 storing 8-bit number issue

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-16, data-conversion, emu8086

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456159/cannot-understand-why-assembly-isnt-working-output-doesnt-show-correct-result-ev) question I asked out why my code isn't working and I thought the issue was only when the program was trying to print out the ASCII characters but I have realized since then that there is another issue.

The task is to accept 8 characters 1 and 0, then save up the result in a register.

My algorithm is as follows:

[image]

And this is the part of my code which is supposed do that:

```
    mov cx,0
    mov bl,8
input:
    mov ah,07h
    int 21h

    cmp al,46
    sub al,30h

    cmp al,0
    je valid
    cmp al,1
    je valid
    jmp input

valid:
    sub bl,1
    cmp bl,0
    je exit
    
    shl cl,1
    add cl,al
    jmp input
```

But when I check out the register `cl` using the emulator it never really shows me what I want; for example if I type `11000000` the value `60h` ends up being saved in the `cl` register which obviously is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one number in your count.  `11000000` (your test case) is `0C0h`, but `60h` is `1100000` (one fewer zero).

Comment: Why is this happening tho?

Comment: Ok, that's an overcomplicated way to write `cmp al,1` / `ja input` like Sep's answer showed, to check that it's not unsigned-above 1.  Never write a `jcc` that goes forward one instruction over a `jmp`, just do a jump with the opposite condition to the `jmp` target.  (Unless it's so far away that it's too far for a short jump.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I type 11000000 the value 60h ends up being saved in the cl register which obviously is not correct.What am I doing wrong?

The code is correct in asking for 8 valid binary digits. However, **because of the particular emplacement of the instructions that decide about leaving the loop**, the eighth digit is not stored in the CL register. You didn't allow `shl cl,1` `add cl,al` to happen on that eighth digit.

The *quick fix* is to change your code from:

```
valid:
    sub bl,1
    cmp bl,0
    je exit       <<< exits too soon the 8th time
    
    shl cl,1      <<< these need to execute 
    add cl,al     <<<   the 8th time also
    jmp input
```

to:

```
valid:
    shl  cl, 1
    add  cl, al
    dec  bl
    jnz  input
```

For a better/optimized version of this same loop, read my answer to your previous question [Cannot understand why assembly isnt working output doesnt show correct result even tho value is copied correctly from the value register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456159/cannot-understand-why-assembly-isnt-working-output-doesnt-show-correct-result-ev)